# Mail is not sending in laravel 5 error

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have created this 2 function in my home controller file

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use App\MediaBuzzPlayer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\MediaBuzzTeam;
use App\PerformanceBuzz;
use App\ArticleCategories;
use App\Fixture;
use App\Player;
use App\Page;
use App\ContactEmail as ContactEmail;
use Mail;
use Auth;
use DB;

class HomeController extends Controller {

 public function getContact()
    {
        return view('contact-us');
    }

    public function postContact(Request $request)
    {    
         $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message'=>'required'
        ]);
      ContactEmail::create($request->only([
            'name',
            'email',
            'message',
        ]));
        $myEmail = 'shivangi.iihglobal@gmail.com';
        Mail::to($myEmail)->send();
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Thanks! We shall get back to you soon.', 
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
       return redirect('home');
    }

}


?>
```

When i submit contact us page mail can not send to my email id i have this type of error at that time

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail::send() must be an instance of Illuminate\Mail\Mailable, none given, called in /var/www/html/footyindexscout/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php on line 343
```

please help me for this i am new to laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try Mail::send('view name', ['data'=>$data], function($message)
                    {
                        $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'Email Message')->subject('Enquiry From Page!');
                    });
```

It will work for me

Answer (score 0):

You should create child of [Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#sending-mail) object and send it as a parameter to Mail::send() method